# Multiplatform office app for iOS/Android that supports offline editing and Google Drive sync

Tags: android, file-synchronization, offline, google-apps, ipad-app

I teach at a middle school where students can't access the net while in class. They have devices like the ipad or android.

For assignments I want them to create a Google Doc file and then to share it with me. I assumed that the Google Docs/Google Drive application would automatically let you edit docs in offline mode and then sync later. However, when testing on my ipad 1, I see that this is NOT the case. If you enable offline mode, that allows you to view the doc only without having the ability to edit it. Which seems absurd. (Could this issue be limited to ipad 1?)

Is there another free or low-cost android + ios solution that enables offline editing and cloud syncing. I prefer Google Docs (because I can organize student folders hierarchically), but I'm open to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: the key detail is that in my use case the NEW document is created on the mobile device in offline mode and then is to be synced to Google. It's fairly easily to take an existing Google Doc and edit in offline mode.